# Filter with IMPORTRANGE need data from 2 Sheets, whould i use query, vlookup, match?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, join, import, vlookup

im trying to simplify my SS with 1 formula instead of what im doing in cols C, D and E with formulas in every row

basically on my example i get data to col B from Derivative sheet on source SS and need to get data to cols C, D and E from Instruments sheet

where Instruments!B:B = Derivatives!B:B - link between those 2 sheets

it should be something like INNER JOIN with SQL, so i tried with query, match, vlookup and couldnt do it, probably cos my lack of skills

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kDzlX355DX5nPi64At8H6mLmy5EFyDbwtOkqtV0NdPA/edit#gid=644376355)

Source SS I import daily from brazilian stock exchance and overwrite its content, quite big

[Source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WZhfbD3BGg71YZUhAr9gW_ii_b3YduOtzO19JAxni7I/edit#gid=170975323)

end result i want would be one formula in C1, D1, and E1, as i have on other Cols

if help in col C i can adapt to the other cols easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete everything in range C2:E and use this in C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B; {
 IMPORTRANGE(Config!B3; "Instruments!B:B")\
 IMPORTRANGE(Config!B3; "Instruments!K:K")\
 IMPORTRANGE(Config!B3; "Instruments!T:T")\
 IMPORTRANGE(Config!B3; "Instruments!AJ:AJ")}; {2\ 3\ 4}; 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: worked perfectly, easier than what i was trying, indeed i couldnt reach that answer, living and learning, thanks

Comment: @player0 Double check Vlookup [is_sorted] when set to `1` i think `0` Dosen't returen all data ( I tested the formula in a  different example  with cell refrences instead of IMPORTRANGE ).

Comment: @player0 my bad, I found the mistake i changed ` \ ` to ` , ` instead of ` ; ` in range array.

Answer (score 0):

### Simplified example

What I understand is that you want to get [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) output from multiple ranges in one formula, one table and diffrent indexes or columns.

To simplify the answer of *[player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0)*  so it can be used in general cases, lets streamline the problem in one sheet one tab without [`importrange`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) instead we use cell references.

> **Paste** this formula next to the **search_key** "State", Take a look at the [**Example Sheet.**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19LHxq-dgobYKIe9UBrPefThT1fx7dDLQ76XwWdRpfxI/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F4:F, {
 A4:D11;
 A14:D20;
 A24:D31}, {4, 3, 2}, 0)))
```

[image]

### Explanation

- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) the search_key range `F4:F` in the stacked ranges of source tables `{ A4:D11; A14:D20; A24:D31}` Meaning `{ table1; table2; table3}`.
- Set the [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) index to `{4, 3, 2}` In order to return multiple values, we used multiple indexs numbers ( columns 4, 3, 2 ) enclosed in curly brackets.
- In the [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) formula, we have created an array using Curly Brackets `{}`. But by default, [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) is not an Array Formula, Therefore, an [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) should be used to wrap the formula.